# Concatenating a string to elements of a matrix

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, concatenation

Given a matrix:

```
A= [1; 3 ; 4 ; 6 ; 8; 9 ; 10]
```

I want to concatenate a string 'Room' with this matrix (for that, the matrix may be converted into string) and I want to display the result like this:

```
'Room1, Room3, Room4 , Room6 , Room8, Room9, Room10'
```

i.e separated by commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `arrayfun`:

```
res = arrayfun(@(x) sprintf('Room%d',x), A, 'Uni', false )
```

Or, if you want a single string output:

```
res = sprintf('Room%d, ', A);
res = res(1:end-2);  %// remove trailing space and comma
```